# Notices when executing script?

Tags: php

Why do I get notices when I execute a php file on my local server? Does that mean there is an error in my file? Notices like:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant l - assumed 'l' in C:\xampp\htdocs\weekday.php on line 3  
Notice: Use of undefined constant Monday - assumed 'Monday' in C:\xampp\htdocs\weekday.php on line 6*
```

Comment: Four downvotes and not even a single comment to the question (which has 5 answers)? Weird...

Answer (score 2):

You are likely getting notices because you have debugging turned on. It probably looks something like this:

```
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set('display_errors', True);
```

To define a constant you need to do

```
   define("Monday","value");
```

Also it is a php convention to name constants with all upper case. I suggest you stick to this convention so you can differentiate a constant from a regular string when reading your code.

Comment: as my reputation is too low(only 1).. i couldn't.if you dont mind can you mark it for me as a nice question.

Answer (score 1):

These notices are there to tell you *exactly* where the problem is.

Look at line 3 of weekday.php and you'll see a place where you use `l` and realise that it's an undefined constant (look up constants)

You probably mean it to be a variable (look up variables - they start with a $ like `$l` in PHP) or a string constant (look up strings - they are surrounded by quotes like `"l"` or `'l'`)

going by the mention of "Monday" I'm going to assume you meant it to be a string.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Notice means you have an error. As you can see it explains where the error is

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between errors and notices. An error will stop your script running; a notice is PHP telling you that there's something up with your script, and it's guessing what you actually meant.

A notice like:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant Monday - assumed 'Monday' in C:\xampp\htdocs\weekday.php on line 6*
```

Means that you're using something like:

```
if ($day == Monday) .....
```

PHP is guess that you mean a string with the text of Monday in it, and it's right.

You don't have to fix notices - your code will still run. But it's definitely a good idea to do so - it'll make sure that your script executes exactly as you intend.